# Convergent Sequence function bijection

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone please help me solve this problem, I am completely lost:

Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence with 
$$ A = \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n.$$
Suppose, $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a bijection (i.e one-to- one correspondence) of naturals. Define a new sequence $b_n=a_{f(n)}$.

Prove or disprove: 
$$A=\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n.$$

Comment: it is true if f is an increasing function.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam The only increasing bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is the identity function, so what you have said is not very interesting.

Comment: @Dylan could you help me out please? Appreciate you modding the post.

Comment: @Mathcouldbefun Jonh's answer is essentially the same as the one I would have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of limit for a given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that $|A-a_n|<\epsilon$ if $n> N$.

Notice that $\{a_0,...,a_N\}$ is finite, so $b_k\neq a_0,...,a_N$ if $k>K$ for a sufficiently large $K$. This implies $|A-b_k|<\epsilon$ if $k>K$.

As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary the definition of limit gives you $A=\lim_k b_k$.